# Google Script - Creating PDF doesn't reflect changes in Document

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script in a spreadsheet that receives responses from a Form. Using these responses and a template Google document, I create a new Document from the template and then replace placeholders (e.g. '##CLIENT##') with the appropriate data. Works great. I then try to create a PDF copy in the same folder. The problem is that the PDF is of the original template without the placeholders replaced... 
I tried adding a break to let the document update with: `Utilities.sleep(15000);` This doesn't help. I guess I am not understanding how the document is being passed between my functions?

Global Variables

```
var SOURCE_TEMPLATE = "{Document ID Here}";
var TARGET_FOLDER = "{Folder ID Here}";
```

Code:

```
//Get headers from spreadsheet and create a sorted array
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

// The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
// Assign values for each submission

if (e && e.namedValues){
var array_fields =[];

var project_manager = e.namedValues[headers[1]].toString();
var client = e.namedValues[headers[2]].toString();
var client_number = e.namedValues[headers[3]].toString();
var project_title = e.namedValues[headers[4]].toString();
var project_number = e.namedValues[headers[5]].toString();
var project_engineer = e.namedValues[headers[6]].toString();
var job_type = e.namedValues[headers[7]].toString();
var completion_date = e.namedValues[headers[14]].toString();
var project_cost = e.namedValues[headers[15]].toString();
var time = get_time();

array_fields.push(project_manager,client,client_number,project_title,pad(project_number),project_engineer,job_type,completion_date,'$'+ add_commas(project_cost),time);

var key_array  = ['##PROJECTMANAGER##','##CLIENT##','##CLIENTNUMBER##','##PROJECTTITLE##','##PROJECTNUMBER##','##PROJECTENGINEER##','##JOBTYPE##','##COMPLETIONDATE##','##PROJECTCOST##','##DATE##'];

var target = createDuplicateDocument(SOURCE_TEMPLATE, client_number + "-" + pad(project_number) +  " " + project_title + " Order Entry");

Logger.log("Created new document:" + target.getId());

for(var i=0; i<array_fields.length; i++) {
  var key = key_array[i]
  var value = array_fields[i]
  replaceParagraph(target, key, value);
}
Utilities.sleep(15000); 
savePDF(target); 

}

}
```

savePDf Function

```
function savePDF(doc) {

var docblob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
var folder =  DocsList.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER);
docblob.setName(doc.getName())
folder.createFile(docblob);

}
```

So the savePDF function should create a PDF copy of the filled document but instead gives me a PDF of the template document, or the new document before it is filled it. 
The Logs show the correct document ID from `target.getID()` So I'm not sure why `target` isn't passed to `savePDF` properly. I feel like it's some small mistake but I can't determine what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveAndClose()) to update the document before converting it.

In your code :

```
function savePDF(doc) {
  doc.saveAndClose();
  var docblob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
  var folder =  DocsList.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER);
  docblob.setName(doc.getName())
  folder.createFile(docblob);
}
```

You don't need the sleep delay, you can remove it unless you want to wait for 15 seconds ;-)

Comment: Ahh, didn't know about saveAndClose(). Learned something new. Thanks so much! Sleep was a last ditch idea, I was hoping I didn't need it.